# Chrome DevTools does not parse JS object if written multiline

Tags: javascript, devtools

Open a Chrome DevTools. Go to Console tab. Write this code:

```
{ "@context": "http://schema.org/", "name": "John" }
```

It would be recognized as a valid JS object.

Now write it as a multiline code snippet:

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "name": "John"
}
```

You get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Why is it so? What is wrong about this multiline code snippet?

Comment: If you assign this to a let/const/var it will work. 
```const a = {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "name": "John"
}```

Comment: and the same behaviour occurs both on multiline and single line if you don't assign the literal to a variable (in FF)

Comment: The console in the chrome dev tools is a REPL. So a single line input is treated differently to how it would be in an actual source file. A single line of code in a REPL is treated as expression, due to that `{ "@context": "http://schema.org/", "name": "John" }` is valid as single line in the REPL console, even so it isn't valid JavaScript on its own.

Comment: @t.niese but if you write a simple multiline function it works. Even though the first line of the function declaration is not a complete syntax without the end line (ending })

Comment: @AliRadan `but if you write a simple multiline function it works.` and what is the problem about that? The REPL accepts valid JavaScript code. But it also accepts parts of an statement as single line that is immediately evaluated, but which on its own would not be valid JavaScript code (only if it is part of an statement).

Answer (score 2):

The console in the chrome dev tools is a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) (read–eval–print loop).

So a single line input is treated differently to how it would be in an actual source file. A single line of code in a REPL is treated as expression.

Due to that `{ "@context": "http://schema.org/", "name": "John" }` is valid as single line in the REPL console, even so it isn't valid JavaScript on its own.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment above, if you write multiline function, it works. Though the first line of a multifunction is not a valid JavaScript syntax, because it does not have closing curly brace.

Comment: @AliRadan again `{ "@context": "http://schema.org/", "name": "John" }` on its own is not a valid JavaScript statement, no matter if it is a single line or spread over multiple lines. It is only valid as part of an statement like `let str = { "@context": "http://schema.org/", "name": "John" }`. If you input a single line to a REPL, then it also accepts code that is not a full statement but only part of an expression. So a `{ "@context": "http://schema.org/", "name": "John" }` that is actually not valid JS is accept in REPL if it is a single line. ...

Comment: @AliRadan ... `if you write multiline function, it works` a function statement is valid JavaScript on its own, so it is accept by the REPL no matter if it is a single line or multiple line input.